# Sonarqube version 9.9. Encryption Error: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 6 bytes

Tags: encryption, sonarqube

I followed the instruction from

https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.9/instance-administration/security/

and generated new secret which I added into my sonar.properties file, I restarted the pod and can see the page where I can encrypt anything which I need to
[sonarqube-encrypt screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDhZQ.png)

However when I click on Encrypt, it say contact admin and print error message in the log as below

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 6 bytes` 
I have tried passing various lengths for this field but still get the same error, so not sure what am I missing.

I created a secret and config map to create the sonar.properties file, which will point to the

```
$ cat sonar.properties
sonar.secretKeyPath=/opt/sonar/sonar-secret.txt
```

And I can see the base64 secret key

```
base64 -i /opt/sonar/sonar-secret.txt
ab4iof70djuGCo--------CqWHxeq435FXSK5Ommg=
```

But not too sure why the error in the log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 6 bytes
```

and what do I need to change to fix it, so any help will be appreciated.